# fusionchart column3d change caption on change of seriesname

Tags: jquery, fusioncharts

I have used fusionchart column3d to display graph like below jsfiddle.

```
 <http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/MSDV4/>
```

Now i want to change caption on change of graph seriesname. e.g- if i disable all graph except food product then caption should show food product and vice verca.

Comment: I hope by disabling, you mean by hiding them through legend interactivity. In this case the caption should not change, cause the entire data has not change. Its just a part you are currently highlighting.

Comment: pallab, isn't there any option upon through we can change caption by hiding or showing legend interactivity?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to [legendItemClicked](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events.html#event-legendItemClicked) event by passing a callback. In your callback you can write the logic to find the series name to shown on the caption according to your requirement. After the finding the new caption value, the caption can be changed dynamically. 
Like this :

```
evtObj.sender.setChartAttribute("caption",valuetobedisplayed);
```

evtObj and dataObj will be passed to the callback assigned when the event is triggered.